# Jacoco + Cucumber + Maven setup

Tags: maven, cucumber, jacoco

I've searched previously and used the answers regarding this question but I ended up in a point where I am not sure it is possible to continue and I want to make sure that jacoco suports this.
   I have a multimodule maven project and I am using cucumber for integration tests:

```
<modules>
  <module>a</module>
  <module>b</module>
  <module>c</module>
</modules>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>env-local</id>
        <modules>
            <module>acceptance-tests</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

The acceptance-tests module is not defined in the  tag of the parent pom but acceptance-tests pom.xml has the same parent defined as the rest of the modules.

The problem is that ALL integration tests are in the acceptance-tests. I don't even have a src/main/java folder in this module. Most of the examples I found have acceptance tests in each module and coverage is generated for the code that belongs to that module.

In my case I need to generate a report with all the classes that are used, even if they are from another module. I also managed to do this but I can only find the coverage for the 'first level': if a class is used directly from spb-acceptance it is included in the report but I can't find any information about the classes that are used indirectly.

Can this kind of coverage be achieved with jacoco ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Maven uses a depth-first approach when it builds the project. That is, it will finish everything in a module before moving on to the next.

The result is that

- The production classes gets compiled
- The production classes gets instrumented so code coverage can be measured
- Test are executed and usage is recorded
- Usage result is collected
- Repeat with next module

This is where it breaks, the new module that are dependent on the previous will use the dependency generated. The jar that now is cached in your local Maven cache. The classes in the jar isn't instrumented and no usage will be recorded for them.

A solution I have used is to

- Compile all code
- Instrument the code
- Execute all tests
- Consolidate and build the report

I write a [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2012/02/18/test-coverage-in-a-multi-module-maven-project) about a couple of years ago.

Comment: I will have a look in the weekend and see if I can apply this solution. Thank you for your response, at least now I know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not reusing the jacoco-it.exec file. It worked when I had a module but for a submodule it was going in the module target and it could not reuse the file

```
<modules>
  <module>a</module>
  <module>b</module>
  <module>c</module>
</modules>
```

So it computed the coverage for the modules that didn't have modules themselves.
If b has b1 and b2, using this entry ${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec 
for sonar.jacoco.itReportPath it was looking for the file in the target of b, not the target of the main pom.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with a multi module project, I created a [complete simple demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git) showing unit, integration, cucumber tests. The test coverage is shown via Jacoco. 
You can see in module3 Cucumber tests.

- Multi module project
- Unit test (via mvn clean install)
- Integration test (via mvn clean install -P integration-test)
- **Cucumber tests** (via mvn clean install) - to demo unit/it-testing
- Jacoco - test coverage ( both aggregate datafile and aggregate reporting)
- FindBugs - code quality

In this project there is a seperate jacoco-aggregate step to combine the Jacoco results of the different modules. You can then browse a index.html file to see the Jacoco results of all modules.

When you use SonarQube, then the aggretation of the Jacoco results of the seperate modules is done by SonarQube. So, you can omit the aggregate step.

I created [another simple project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-UT-IT-FT-jacoco2) solving the problem in a different way.

- Define in the parent pom in section 'build' 'pluginmanagement' the definitions of the failsafe and surefire plugins.
- Refer in each module, where you use these plugings, to the plugins via a very simple reference with groupid and artifactid. That's all.